# Horizontal Transformation of Array (2D)

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, transformation

It's a simple matter of flipping an image horizontally and/or vertically. The premise is that given a 2D integer array that was created from importing a picture, I must create a method with a int[][] param and horizontally flip it before returning void.

The syntax is below:

```
public static void horizontalFlip(int[][] imgArray)
    {
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < imgArray[i].length / 2; j++)
            {
                temp = imgArray[i][j];
                imgArray[i][j] = imgArray[imgArray.length - 1 - i][j];
                imgArray[imgArray.length - 1 - i][j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

I use imgArray as the array param and use temp as a placeholder while the loop swaps pixels, or rather, that was the intention. Currently the window does nothing after prompting the flip. Can somebody help me find the problem with the logic or syntax?

Thanks in advance, please specify any details I should provide
P.S. I can confirm the unreferenced supplied code is functional and tested.

Comment: Really nothing happens? To me it seems as if you do kind of a flip. Have you tried to flip a non symmetrical image?

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you are using `i` instead of `j`. But `i` will not stop after halfway, but it is continued and re-swap the array.
Here is a correct code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imgArray[i].length / 2; j++) {
        temp = imgArray[i][j];
        imgArray[i][j] = imgArray[i][imgArray.length - 1 - j];
        imgArray[i][imgArray.length - 1 -j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Or if you want to swap columns, not rows :

```
for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length / 2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imgArray[i].length; j++) {
        temp = imgArray[i][j];
        imgArray[i][j] = imgArray[imgArray.length - 1 - i][j];
        imgArray[imgArray.length - 1 -i][j] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i see. Should have been a bit more observant i guess. Funnily enough, the program seems to work just fine with the second bit of code you added (to flip vertically), however the first bit causes an index exception. Compiler seems to point to line 10, which is 
imgArray[i][j] = imgArray[i][imgArray.length - 1 - j];

Can this happen if the width and height are unequal?

Comment: According to the code provided, `i` should be used for **height** and `j` for **width**. Then it will work, no matter if dimensions are equal or not. @user3072912

Answer (score 0):

This will correctly flip the image horizontally:

```
public static void horizontalFlip(int[][] imgArray)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgArray[i].length/2; j++) {
        temp = imgArray[i][j];
        imgArray[i][j] = imgArray[i][imgArray[i].length - 1 - j];
        imgArray[i][imgArray[i].length - 1 - j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my solution below,

```
for(int i=0; i<matrix.length / 2; i++)
{
    int[] row = matrix[i];
    int[] temp = row;
    matrix[i] = matrix[matrix.length - 1];
    matrix[matrix.length - 1] = row;
}
```