# Converting a column to a row using Google Script

Tags: excel, google-apps-script

I'm new with Google script and I want to transform a content of a column into a row like below :[image]

The result will be like below  :

[image]

I tried this code,but there is no result appearing when executing :

```
function test() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXX");
var s = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXX");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('iGV'); 
var sheete = s.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
var rangee = sheete.getRange("A1:F7");   
var values = sheet.getRange("F11:F17").getValues(); 
for (var i = 0; i<values.length;i++){
for(var j=0;i<rangee.length;j++){
rangee [i][1]=values[1][j];}}}
```

Comment: Which rows/column you want to transform ?

Comment: As i mentioned in the pictures I want to transform the content of the column in the first picture to a row like in the second picture.

Comment: I get that column to row, but you want to transform only Column A or what ?

Comment: Any column I want ,like A for example.

Comment: Maybe you'll find this helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28130828/horizontal-transformation-of-array-2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a much simpler built-in solution (see below). Simply set 'transposed' to 'true' in the copyTo() method:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('sourceSheet');
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('targetSheet');    
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var values = sourceRange.getValues();
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, values[0].length);
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I also tried to use setFormula('=transpose(XXX)'); the problem here is transpose only accept sheets from the same file

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple transpose:

```
function myTranspose(A) {
  var B=[];
  for(var i=0;i<A[0].length;i++){
    B[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<A.length;j++){
      B[i][j]=A[j][i];
    }
  }
  return B;
}
```

You can set it up with something like this:

```
function testTranspose(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('C1:C8');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var vB=myTranspose(vA);//vA is the value array for the range you want to transpose
  sh.getRange(1,sh.getLastColumn()+2,vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying you code :A in myTranspose function is undefined.

Comment: Look in testTranspose

Answer (score 2):

Rather than setting the cells one at a time, it would be more efficient to created a nested array, then set the entire range at once. setValues() requires a nested array, the outer array being the rows, the inner array being the columns. So this test code takes the values in "A1:A10" and puts them in "B1:K1".

```
function columnToRow() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getRange("a1:a10").getValues();
var rowValues = [[]]; //create an array within an array. Outter array is the row. Inner array are the columns.
for (i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
  rowValues[0].push(values[i][0]); //push the values to the inner array (columns array)
}
var setRange = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, rowValues[0].length) //(row, column, numRows, numColumns)
setRange.setValues(rowValues);
}
```